# Change table tr td field="value"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and want to change the field value of data-admin="**newvalue**".
How can i do this if i only have e.g. the number of the table `<tr>` id="67" ?

First when i click on the edit button the rights are displayed correct with 0 and 2. After press the "Click to change" button the data-admin value should change to zero, but when i press the edit button again it is not really changing.

I have changed my first postet example considered to the post from: Rory McCrossan. I hope it is now more clear.

```js
var userid = 67;

$(document).ready(function() {
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $('#mytable').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "info": false
  });
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------    
  $("#mytable").on('click', 'tbody tr button', function(e) {
    userid = $(this).attr('data-data');
    var username = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(0)').text();
    var adminright = parseInt($(this).attr('data-admin'));

    $("#display").html("Number: " + userid + " / Username: " + username + " / Right: " + adminright);

    e.preventDefault();
  });
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------      
  $("#myButton").bind("click", function(e) {

    $('#' + userid).find('button').data('admin', '1');
    var line = $('#mytable').dataTable().fnGetPosition(document.getElementById(userid));
    $('#mytable').dataTable().fnUpdate("Administrator", line, 1);

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<p id="display">INFO
  <p>
    <br>
    <button id="myButton" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-block btn-default">Click to change</button>
    <br>
    <table id="mytable" class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed nowrap">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Username</th>
          <th>Right</th>
          <th>Last Login</th>
          <th>Count</th>
          <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id="67">
          <td>Thomas</td>
          <td>User</td>
          <td>2015-12-14 11:03:45</td>
          <td>34</td>
          <td>
            <button id="select-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-block btn-default" data-data="67" data-admin="2">Edit</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="82">
          <td>Peter</td>
          <td>User</td>
          <td>2014-03-26 08:51:55</td>
          <td>33</td>
          <td>
            <button id="select-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-block btn-default" data-data="82" data-admin="0">Edit</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: if you want to change the text of td use `.text()` or `.html()`. example `$('#67').text('newvalue');`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly note that your HTML is invalid as you have used non-standard attributes and duplicated `id`. If you wish to store additional information with an element, use `data-*` attributes. `id` must be unique within a `document`. To group elements use classes. Try this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr id="67">
        <td>first</td>
        <td>Administrator</td>
        <td>2015-12-14 11:03:45</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="select-btn btn btn-xs btn-block btn-default" data-data="123" data-admin="2">Edit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="82">
        <td>second</td>
        <td>User</td>
        <td>2014-03-26 08:51:55</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="select-btn btn btn-xs btn-block btn-default" data-data="852" data-admin="0">Edit</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

From there you can use the `id` of the `tr` to select the element and traverse to the `button` before changing the required `data` attribute:

```
$('#67').find('button').data('admin', 'newvalue');
```

Note that the `data()` method affects the value stored in jQuery's internal cache and won't visibly affect the DOM.